# mostrar formato moneda a valores cargados de una columna - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

buen dia, tengo una tabla "https://material-table-core.com" la cual me muestra la información de mi base de datos, pero necesito que la tabla me muestre los valores de la columna "valor_t2" en formato moneda pero lo he intentado pero no he logrado hacerlo, envió mi código:

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-rumple-x6fzwi?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en el ejemplo que proporcionas, puedes agregar una funcion `toMoney` y apoyarte de la libreria nativa `Intl`;

Documentacion: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/format

```js
  const toMoney = value => {
    const money = Number(value);

    if (isNaN(money)) {
      return value;
    }

    return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(money)
  }

  console.log(toMoney(20000)); // $20,000.00
  console.log(toMoney(5200)); // $5,200.00
```

Por consiguiente el resultado es el siguiente;

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-montalcini-8c6dku?file=/src/App.js

Comment: no aparece el formato moneda en la suma dentro de la tabla

Comment: Si aparece, incluso sé que el total está en rojo y se renderiza $118,100.00